# Can you use the google analytics API to create the same type of graph as on your google analytics dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm curious to know if there is an easy way to creat a similar graph to embed google analytics into our cms for clients pages, so that they can see the same type of chart that google has on there analytics dashboard.

Comment: I went ahead and wrote something to do this. My answer on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11566804/813115

Answer (score 0):

What *exactly* do you want? If you want to use data collected by Google Analytics, you can use its' [Google Analytics Data Export API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html).

Comment: Want some sort of easy way to create a graph from the google analytics data, essentially exporting the dashboard into a CMS, without having to do all the leg work of pulling each bit of data and recreating it through your own chart. Perhaps theres tool thats already been created for this, im sure pulling google analytics stuff onto a page in a graphical way is quite a common request?

Answer (score 0):

Yes - check out [embeddedanalytics.com](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com).  You define the chart (metrics, dimensions, type) and simply embed a snippet of code into your site.

Disclosure: I work with embeddedanalytics.